# Удаление строки из sqlite3

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite3, datagridview

Всем привет.
Какой день бьюсь над написанием метода, который удаляет строку из sqlite3, данные которой находятся в dataGridView. Программа на Win Form.

Логика, если я правильно мыслю, такова: по клику на нужную строчку в dataGridView, я по идее должен в переменную записать id строки.

После этого выполнить запрос в базу на удаление:

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM Catalog WHERE id = @id";
            SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConn);
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Никак не могу понять, как записать id выбранной мною строки из dataGridView в переменную. И есть ли какие-то особенности выделения в самом dataGridView? Можно выделить всю строку, а можно ячейку. Будет ли это считаться одним и тем же в данном случае?
Пока смог изобразить такое:

```
int id_line = int.Parse(dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Может есть уже у кого готовый пример метода? А то мозги кипят уже... Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение).

```
if (dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Вы действительно хотите удалить запись? Это действие нельзя будет отменить", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                string id = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"DELETE FROM Catalog WHERE id = @id", m_dbConn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Запись была успешно удалена из базы данных", "Удаление записи", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Чтоб выделялась вся строка, выставляем в свойствах dataGridView: SelectionMode в FullRowSelect;

Comment: Не используйте метод `AddWithValue`, он плохой, забудьте про него. Причины: [1](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - достаточно прочесть любую из статей. Используйте взамен метод `Add` с указанием точного типа.

Comment: `id` какой тип имеет: действительно `string` или всё-таки `int`? Или, может быть, `Guid`? Если в БД тип не строка, то применение `AddWithValue` приведёт к плохой производительности. Конечно, на небольших объёмах это не страшно, но лучше писать код сразу правильно.

Comment: Если вы поняли, о чем 2 комментария выше, то отредактируйте пост на правильное решение, чтобы люди потом не копировали у вас плохой код.

Comment: Если честно, то так и не понял, как правильно сделать запрос на удаление....